# If 2 metal spheres are in contact and a charged rod is brought closer, what would the charge on the spheres be when the are separated?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge

Two charged metal spheres L and M are placed in contact.
Before contact L had a net charge of +10e and M a net charge of -10e.
A positively charged rod is brought close to L, but does not touch it.
The two spheres are then separated and the rod is withdrawn.
What is then the charge on each sphere?

I think that when the rod is brought closer to L, the conduction electrons will move to the side closest to the charged rod. Electrons will then move from sphere M to L. So afterwards L is negatively charged and M is positively charged. However, question implies the answer to be an exact numerical charge and I don't know how I am supposed to calculate it.

Answer (score 1):

When the two spheres are brought together, the extra electrons on M will move to L, leaving both neutral.  Without knowing the charge on the rod, it would be impossible to predict the quantity of induced charge on the spheres (and probably questionable in any case).

Answer (score 1):

Given the number of degrees of freedom it's hard to predict an exact numerical value, because the given numbers are trivial as once brought in contact, the situation is as good as two neutral spheres having been brought together. This is because the spheres are metallic thus redistribute to neutralise themselves. The strength of charge on rod, the distance between the two, and even the temperature play a role in determining what is asked. The question probably asks you to qualitatively distinguish the charges.

What can be predicted, and this might be an answer to the "what is" in question is, the metal spheres will have an equal magnitude of charges with opposite signs since no charges were brought into or taken out from a neutral system. This could be an exercise question for law of conservation of charge which in itself is beautiful.